# Unable to render HTML conditionally with Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app that uses Razor. Part of the HTML is rendered via a loop. I need to conditionally create an opening/closing  element. For some reason, the view renderer throws a runtime error when i try the following:

```
  <div id="content">
    <div id="banner">@ViewBag.BannerText</div></br>

    <div id="group">
@{ 
  int currentID = 0;
  foreach (Item item in ViewBag.Items) {
  if (currentID != item.ID) {
      <div>
        <h3>@item.GetItemTitle()</h3>    
        <div>@item.Name</div>
  }

  if (currentID != item.ID) {
    @Html.Raw("</div>");
    currentID = item.ID;   
  }
}
</div>
</div>
```

Everything looks correct to me. However, I can't figure out why it won't work. It seems like everytime I had the @Html.Raw("") it fails. However, if I remove the conditional if-statement and the @Html.Raw(""); it works fine.

Comment: What runtime error. Supply details.

Comment: Why do you need `@Html.Raw`?  Does `@:</div>` not work?

Comment: Tried @:</div>, however that did not work. The runtime error I am getting is: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your closing DIV must be in the same block as the opening DIV. Use @Html.Raw on your opening DIV and your problem should go away.